# Xquery transformation convert int to string

Tags: xquery

I want to XQuery transformation function to convert int to string.

I have XQuery transformation as below:

```
<ns8:postCode>{ fn:string(data($customer/ns9:postCode)) }</ns8:postCode>
```

I am trying to convert int to string but still the above line gives error that 
it doesn't match target schema.Source is int and target is string.

I also tried:

```
<ns8:postCode>{ xs:string(xs:integer(data($customer/ns9:postCode))) }</ns8:postCode>
```

but I'm getting same error

Comment: You'll need to provide the error messages (and preferably relevant parts of the schemas) for this question to be answerable.

Answer (score 0):

`fn:data()` will return whatever atomic type (or `untypedAtomic`) is defined for `ns9:postCode`. If you want a string, there's no reason to get the atomic type - or do any other type conversions - first:

```
<ns8:postCode>{ fn:string($customer/ns9:postCode) }</ns8:postCode>
```

Your question doesn't provide the error in question, but it's possible that `<ns8:postCode>` is defined as a type other than `xs:string`. If that element contains an `xs:string`, and the schema defines that element as `xs:integer` it's going to throw a type mismatch error.